# Filter response object based on an array of whitelisted ids

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, refactoring

How to Filter a response object based on an array of whitelisted ids?

I've a working version but i don't like the nested `forEach` here and i wonder if there is a way to improve it?!

```
function WhitelistCtrl($scope) {
    var visible = [];
    var whitelist = [123, 456]; // items to be visible
    var response = [{
        id: 123,
        name: 'my object #1'
    }, {
        id: 456,
        name: 'my object #2'
    }, {
        id: 789,
        name: 'my object #3'
    }];

    angular.forEach(whitelist, function (id) {
        angular.forEach(response, function (item) {
            if (id === item.id) {
                visible.push(item);
            }
        });
    });

}
```

Here is a JSFiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/gearsdigital/rv6vq2L7/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not much familiar with `Anglar ForEeach` but you can achive this using native javascript `filter` like bellow

```
visible = response.filter(function(item){
    return (whitelist.indexOf(item.id) > -1);
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mkdskd/rv6vq2L7/1/)

**NOTE:-** IE8 doesn't supports `.filter`.